# Electron: Using a module in the main process

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to use a module I made myself in the main process in Electron,
but for some reason it doesn't work as intended (at all).

In the main process (main.js), I define the module

```
const connection = require('connection');
```

That module exports a function called init

```
var Connection = {
    init: function() {
        ...
    },
    ....
}
module.exports = Connection;
```

But when trying to call this method, through the main process (main.js) on a webpage. (login.html)

```
var Connection = require('electron').remote.connection;
Connection.init();
```

It tells me that Connection is undefined.
I know the Connection module I made works, because I've used it just fine in the renderer process.

The reason that I want to use the entire Connection module in the main process, is so that I could keep that connection alive and performing tasks even when the user goes to another page.

I've searched all around but can't seem to find the solution to my problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer,
the proper way to use a module through the main process would be to use this:

```
require('electron').remote.require('connection');
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.Worked for me.

Comment: If is useful for someone now a days (May 2021). I'm working with newer version of electron (v11), my setup includes context isolation , a preload, nodeIntegration = false and remote disabled. And I can import the module without using remote and with modern "import FileModule from './file.js';" syntax. So as of today you can omit using remote to require your module and it works fine.